# How to bundle jre in eclipse rcp app in Mac

Tags: macos, rcp

I want to bundle jre6 in my RCP Application on MAC Operating system. Any idea how I can do this ?
I tried to use (bundle jre) option from product configuration but it did not works (not exported jre in my RCP Application folder).
However I can bundle it on windows successfully by just copying jre folder into my Application folder and my RCP Application will be executed with this jre.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the following thread: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/518603/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven Tycho to build your product, you could add the JRE as bundle and use the setJvm p2 Touchpoint action to configure the RCP application to use the bundled JRE. See this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50303681/1158146