# Bundle JRE with RCP plugin based application by tycho maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I have the RCP application that based on plugin model. I would like to put JRE to final artifacts that created by Maven+Tycho.  I tried to follow to these recomendation

[including-a-jre-in-a-tycho-build](https://codeiseasy.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/including-a-jre-in-a-tycho-build/)

[bundle-jre-along-with-your-product](http://eclipseo.blogspot.ru/2014/11/bundle-jre-along-with-your-product.html)

I created one more feature project where required JRE is put to folder in root of the feature project. In my case this jre/win64. The I add feature to product definition. But I don't understand How shall I notify maven process that responsible for product distribution creating about JRE in my feature project
my build properties file is

```
bin.includes=feature.xml
root.win32.win32.x86_64= ./jre/win64
```

Also I created new pom.xml and add to parent pom.xml
I use tycho 1.1.0 and Eclipse Neon.3 as platform

Answer (score 4):

For my open source Eclipse RCP e4 application, I am bundling the OpenJDK binaries thankfully provided by Azul. Check out the [Github project](https://github.com/buchen/bundled-jre) that builds the Eclipse feature.

In short, it uses the idea outlined in the above mentioned blog post [Including a JRE in a Tycho build](https://codeiseasy.wordpress.com/2012/07/31/including-a-jre-in-a-tycho-build/). The advantage over using root files is that the JRE can be more easily updated via P2 (in case of root files, the running JRE on Windows might prevent the replacement with an updated JRE).

The [Tycho](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/) build in [that repository](https://github.com/buchen/bundled-jre) does:

- Download the JDK builds from [Zulu](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/)
- Create bundles with the appropriate `setJvm` [p2 Touchpoint Instructions](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_actions_touchpoints.html)
- Create a feature with all JRE bundles and a repository for use in other builds
- Create an RCP e4 application with self-update functionality to test the packaged JRE

Using this in your RCP product is than a matter of adding the feature to the product definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?pde version="3.5"?>

<product name="Test Product">
    <features>
        <feature id="test.feature"/>
        <feature id="org.eclipse.e4.rcp"/>

        <feature id="name.abuchen.zulu.jre.feature"/>

    </features>
</product>
```